# pouchdb replication conflict resolution with remote wins

Tags: pouchdb

I am trying to implement a resolution strategy where server revisions overwrite local revisions. With the arg on the `replicate().on('change', ..` looking like

```js
{
  _id: "xyz",
    _rev: "2-efg",
      _conflicts: [
        {
          _id: 'xyz',
          _rev: '2-mon'
```

Is there a way to know if the object itself is local (where replication is called) or remote and if the `_conflicts` array objects are remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [couchdb wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts) this is not possible.

> Another thing to notice is that peers do not have to be configured or tracked. You can do regular replications to peers, or you can do one-off, ad-hoc pushes or pulls. After the replication has taken place, there is no record kept of which peer any particular document or revision came from.